# Issue with jQuery appendTo Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have designed a form where the user can enter his comment using "Add Comment" button.
whatever comment user enters is added to the list of Comments on the page.
I am appending new comment using "appendTo()" function. but whenever I refresh the page all the comments added using "appendTo()" function are lost.
My question is, is there any way to retain the comments even after "Page Refresh"?
Any hint or a demo example would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You have to add the comments into a database and retrieve the comments from it on the page load

Comment: @Mathboy But dont you think this approach will be inefficient as  It will increase overhead of database calls every time when user adds a new comment?

Comment: @Pranjali. No **inefficient** will be to "save" the comment only in the client page, Thus comment will not be saved the next page visit... **That's inefficient**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to retain the comments even after "Page Refresh"?

No you can't. If you "save" the data only in the client side it will not be saved after Page refresh. **HTTP is stateless**. once the response reached the client, the server doesn't "know" the client anymore.

If you want the comment to be saved, You will have to use some sort of Data Base that stores the comments.

Additional to the appending you should make an `AJAX` `post` request to add the comment to the server.

Comment: @Mathboy But dont you think this approach will be inefficient as  It will increase overhead of database calls every time when user adds a new comment?

Comment: @Pranjali. No **inefficient** will be to "save" the comment only in the client page, Thus comment will not be saved the next page visit... **That's inefficient**

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the comments in the server, ie a database.

I suggest using a form filled with each new comments and ajax posted when a user sumits.

```
<form action="post_comments" method="POST">
  <input id="new_comment" type="hidden" name="comment" />
</form>

<div id="comments">
  <input type="button" id="add_comment" value="Add Comment" />
  <textarea>comment 1</textarea>
  <textarea>comment 2</textarea>
</div>
```

So your comments will be kept at refresh.
Do you know how to post it with ajax ?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with 'ajax'. I will try to follow the approach you suggested and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a couple of options here. You could create a database for the back end or you could get the script to save the comments to an xml document. That the comments could be easily viewed by an RSS reader also.